# Can't get the inner div to scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-dom

The problem I am having is that with the code structure below (Using React), I am unable to make the *ScrollView* scroll.

```
<Window>
    <Sidebar/>
    <Body>
        <ScrollView>
            <Container>
                // Inner Container Content goes here
            </Container>
        </ScrollView>
    </Body>
</Window>
```

- The *Window* has `overflow: none;` as well as setting its size to 100% height and width.
- The *Sidebar* and *Body* just have CSS properties defining their relative sizes to each other in different states.
- The *ScrollView* has `overflow-y: scroll` as well as height and width properties.
- Finally, *Container* just has sizing and style properties.

My problem mainly has to do with getting *ScrollView*'s `overflow-y: scroll;` property to actually happen despite being a child of *Window*.

I was expecting the *ScrollView* to work regardless but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: can you please add some codepen or minimum re-producible code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.